# "Sign in to Chrome" missing; No syncing options in chrome://settings; Chrome: 37.0.2062.102

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-sync

When I launched Chrome (37.0.2062.102) today, all my extensions were gone, although yesterday everything was fine. I did some research into this issues of course, assuming that my user data is corrupt. One "solution" was to delete "%LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default" which was what I did, knowing that I synced my browser state anyway.

I use the sync feature for all my Chrome instances since it is available and it worked flawlessly over the years. However, now the "Sign in to Chrome" menu entry is simply missing. I found out that you can sign in via some kind of new profile manager, I never saw before, but then you are not prompted for your sync passphrase and neither extensions nor stored passwords are restored.

When you google for a solution to this, you'll find forum entries and posts from all years for all Chrome versions. Everything outdated and nothing on this specific issue for the most recent Chrome version. Even when you look into Chrome's official help pages, you are always told to use the "Sign in to chrome" menu entry, which obviously isn't possible anymore.

So please, can anyone tell me how I am supposed to sign in and get my broken Chrome instance syncing again?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and re-install?

Comment: Yep. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, by stumbling upon

> chrome://policy

where `SigninAllowed` was flagged `false` and `SyncDisabled` was flagged `true`

These two flags can be set via the following registry keys:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\SigninAllowed
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\SyncDisabled

Just for reference.

Comment: The reason why these values changed from one day to the other, is still something I have to find out. Probably the Admins are enforcing new policies without prior warning.

Comment: Stackexchange forces you to wait 2 days before you are able to accept you own answer. Still one hour left ;)

Comment: I suspect when Chrome is installed on Windows without Admin privileges (and defaults the install the to user directory), these flags get set to disabled.  Anytime I've installed as an Admin I haven't had this issue.

Comment: This is probably because an admin is enforcing these settings with a GPO or something. These settings are located in 2 location, one for the currently logged in user, and one for the whole environment.
I created a REG file containing both situations, for both HKCU and HKLM.

But please be aware that they could be deleted at login or when the policy is updated, so you will have to re-apply them. I created a scheduled task running every other hour to automatically import these settings.
PS: I am the sysadmin applying the GPO :D

Comment: Yes. That was the case. I switched to chromium portable as a consequence ;)

Answer (score 6):

The registry keys that I found to control this were

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\SigninAllowed
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\SyncDisabled
```

rather than

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\SigninAllowed
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\SyncDisabled
```

I had to run `regedt32` as an administrator to update the settings.